# jQuery is behaving strangely after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

After an ajax call I cannot edit the content of the with ajax pulled content anymore.

I cannot edit the contents of the `content` div anymore. Neither `.show()` nor `.animate()` do work anymore.

Does anybody have an idea what is going on?

`index.php`

```
if (!empty($uri)) {
    $first = substr($uri, 0, 1);
    if ($first == '/') {
        $uri = substr($uri, 1);
    }
    if (!empty($uri)) {
        $uri = explode('?', $uri);
        $uri = explode('/', $uri[0]);

        if (isset($uri[1])) {
            $page = $uri[1];
            } else {
            $page = array_shift($uri);
            }

        if ($uri[0] == 'blanc' && empty($uri[1])) {
            $page = 'profile';
        }   
    }
}

$content = Helper::getContent($page);

if (!empty($_GET['ajax'])) {
    echo $content;
} else {
    require_once ('template.php');
}

?>
```

template.php

```
<div class="content">
    <?php
        echo $content;
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: Add some code please.

Comment: I am a bit confused now, I switched the relative sizing off to debug and still it is not working. Could you have a look here please? http://liebdich.biz/blanc. Thanks. I totally do not know what is going on here, it could be something with the ajax and the php `echo`???

Comment: Please use http://jsfiddle.net/ to provide an example next time.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: @Rumplin If the problem is with ajax it does not work in jsfiddle. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to say, that this problem can't be reproduce except on your machine? That can't be true. Javascript is javascript, you are not having network problem, you are having jQuery problems - so it seems.

Comment: @dollarVar FYI, JSFiddle _does_ have AJAX capabilities, but I don't know how (and if) they work though. I don't recommend it for debugging because most probably you'll have to alter your code to make it work with JSFiddle's AJAX.

Comment: @11684 Yeah, cool, thanks for coming back. If JSFIDDLE supports node.js then soon, we are all set for the future. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to recall functions for initializing jquery on your objects after loading the content to your html, since it overwrites all the bindings with the new html objects. Happens to me all the time.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       function initBindings(){
            $('.content .class').click(function(e){

                $.get('site', function(data){
                    $('.content').html(data);
                    initBindings();
                })
                e.preventDefault();

            })
        })
        initBindings();
    })
```

Comment: Can you please explain? How to? Thanks!!

Comment: my answer was premature, obviously. i looked up the link, and cannot see what the problem is...?

Comment: it resizes correctly, even after ajax call, so what is the issue?

Comment: The issue is, that i cannot for example `.hide()`the image in the div `content`. No content is editable with jQuery. As you can see, inside this the ajax content is pulled. That's why it sounded good, that you have to reinitialise after an ajax pull!?!

Comment: The ajax call is inside the `content` div, the content div is editable. The image is on `width` and `height` 100% (on http://liebdich.biz/blanc/pr. Thanks!!

Comment: well, you use hyper.init() in your core.js to initialize something. whatever bindings you use for your desired effects, you have to call them after loading of ajax response. for example, if you used $('#content a').click(function(){$(this).hide()}) binding, you have to recall it after you replace the content div html in $.get callback function : $.get(page, {ajax : 1}, function(data) {
    $('.content').empty().append(data);
                                $('#content a').click(function(){$(this).hide()})
   });

Comment: So abstract, everything you do on the content pulled with ajax, you have to do it in the `success` of the ajax call?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39910/discussion-between-kuro-and-dollarvar)